# Any tools for analyzing long strings

Tags: javascript, php, string, apache, web

In a web application scenario, what is the best/most efficient way to analyze massive strings (30,000+ groups of characters). Using javascript and php separately, I run into the same issue of long run-times while looping and searching for regexs and phrases. After much research, I must ask... is there a preferred framework, language, or strategy for dealing with such processes or anything that is considered best practices to maximize efficiency and resources while not making a user wait 3 minutes for the operation to be performed? Perhaps there is some tuning of the environment I'm working in?

I am using PHP and Javascript on an apache server, but I'm willing to use whatever resources are best equipped for this task.

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Without knowledge of what you are trying to do, you won't get much help.

Comment: I think its pretty clear that i want to loop through a large string looking for key words and phrases - not much more complicates than that...

Comment: I have realized the Apache org has a framework for parsing files called Tika.  In order to use it, i have familiarized myself to some degree with Java.  I have found that writing an application to parse the text from a PDF and looping through the outputted text is FAR more time efficient than asking PHP or Javascript to attempt the task. Furthermore, im sure i can invoke my new text parsing application from a PHP script and ask the computer to run the procedure in the background - whil my web app user goes on his merry way.  Not completely resolved yet, but i think im on track.